Adding a Different Post Type Title to the Custom Post Type Archive Page
I'm working on resolving an issue on a custom-developed WordPress site. Here's what needs to be done:
A custom post type named "Etkinlik" (Event) has been created, and we list events on the "Etkinlik" Archive page. In this listing, we also select the person responsible for the event using a custom metabox (for the personnel, there is another custom post type named "Çalışanlar" - Employees). We want the selected personnel's name to also appear in the area of the "Etkinlik" archive page.
Event archive page
To achieve this, we are trying to fetch the data from the "Çalışanlar" post type using the ID and then retrieve the name using the ->post_title method. However, the data returned always seems to be the "Etkinlik" name. How can we overcome this problem?
Codes We Use(events-arhive.php)
            <!-- EVENT:Item -->
              <?php
              $baslik_etkinlik = get_field('baslik_etkinlik_tr', 'option');
              $alt_baslik_etkinlik = get_field('alt_baslik_etkinlik_tr', 'option');
              $yakindaki_etkinlikler = get_field('yakindaki_etkinlikler_tr', 'option');
              $etkinlikadi = "Etkinlik Adı";
              $egitmenadi = "Eğitmen Adı";
              $subeadi = "Yer";
              $turadi = "Tür";
              $kaydol = "Kaydol";
              ?>

              <?php
              $args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'etkinlik',
                  'posts_per_page' => 6
              );

              $query = new WP_Query($args);

              if ($query->have_posts()) {
                  while ($query->have_posts()) {
                      $query->the_post();
                      $post_data = get_post(); // Veriyi almak için get_post fonksiyonu kullanılır.
                      $etkinlik_bas_saati = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'etkinlik_bas_saati', true);
                      $etkinlik_bit_saati = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'etkinlik_bit_saati', true);
                      $etkinlik_zamani = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'etkinlik_zamani', true);
                      $etkinlikId = get_the_ID(); // Etkinlik ID'sini al

                      $egitmenID = get_post_meta($etkinlikId, 'egitmen', true);

                      $egitmen = get_post($egitmenID);
                      $egitmen_ad = $egitmen->post_title;
                      $egitmen_link = $egitmen->guid;

                      $etkinlik_id = get_the_ID();

                      $subeler_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'subeler', true);
                      $subeadi = "Yer";
                      if (!empty($subeler_id)) {
                          $sube_post = get_post($subeler_id);
                          $sube_name =esc_html($sube_post->post_title) ;
                          $sube_link =esc_html($sube_post->guid) ;
                      }

                      $tur = wp_get_post_terms($etkinlik_id, 'tur');
                      if (!empty($tur) && is_array($tur)) {
                          $ilk_tur = reset($tur);
                          $tur_adi = $ilk_tur->name;
                          $tur_slug = $ilk_tur->slug;
                      }


                      ?>
                      <div
                              class="event-list-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"
                      >
                          <div class="date event-item">
                              <p class="title"><?=date('d.m.Y', strtotime($etkinlik_zamani))?></p>
                              <p class="desc"><?=$etkinlik_bas_saati?> - <?=$etkinlik_bit_saati?></p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="event-item">
                              <p class="title"><?=$etkinlikadi?></p>
                              <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="desc"><?=the_title();?></a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="event-item">
                              <p class="title"><?=$egitmenadi?></p>
                              <a href="<?=$egitmen_link?>" class="desc"><?=$egitmen_ad?></a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="event-item">
                              <p class="title"><?=$subeadi?></p>
                              <a href="<?=$sube_link?>" class="desc"><?=$sube_name?></a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="event-item">
                              <p class="title"><?=$turadi?></p>
                              <a href="/tur/<?=$tur_slug?>" class="desc"><?=$tur_adi?></a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="event-item">
                              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="event-link"><?=$kaydol?></a>
                          </div>
                      </div>

I tried different alternative solutions based on Chatgpt and Google research, but either the title data does not come, which means it appears empty, or the site gives a critical error warning.
